# Why is $E[X\mid \mathcal{G}]=E[X\mid \sigma(\mathcal{G},\mathcal{H})]$ when $\mathcal{H}$ is indepedent of $\sigma(\sigma(X),\mathcal{G})$?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Why is $E[X\mid \mathcal{G}]=E[X\mid \sigma(\mathcal{G},\mathcal{H})]$ when $\mathcal{H}$ is indepedent of $\sigma(\sigma(X),\mathcal{G})$

I tried to use the definition of conditional expectation but I couldnt use the assumption of independence in a proper way which might help me finish the proof. Any hints to get me started?

Comment: If you pick $Z$ to be a version of $E[X|\mathcal{G}]$, you can show that it is also a version of $E[X|\sigma(\mathcal{G},\mathcal{H})]$. Note that for the property $E[Z\mathbb{1}_A] = E[X \mathbb{1}_A]$, you can look at $A = G \cap H$ with $G \in \mathcal{G}$ and $H \in \mathcal{H}$.

Comment: And then we use the dynkin system theorem to conclude for all A in the generated sigma field